# With Mongoid, how to grab a collection of collections (via subdocuments)?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid structure that looks sort of like this:

```
class Site
  has_many :web_pages
  field :name, type: String
  # ... other stuff
end      

class WebPage
  belongs_to :site
  embeds_one :content
  # ... other stuff
end

class Content
  embeds_many :images
  # ... other stuff
end

class Image
  embedded_in :content
  field :title, type: String
  field :bytes, type: Integer
  # ... other stuff
end
```

What I want to do is have a Mongoid query that given a Site name, pull out a collection of Image records, but only the title and bytes fields.

I know I can do this iteratively via Ruby... i.e. I can grab all the WebPages for a given Site (by name), iterate through them and for each, grab it's one Content record and then all the Images for that Content, plucking only the title and bytes fields.  But that's an N+1 query whereas I'm sure there must be a way in a single query to pull out all the Images for all the WebPages for a given Site (by title).

I welcome any suggestions on how to arrange this with Mongoid.

Comment: There are no JOINs in MongoDB so you're stuck querying a single collection at a time; your choices are to do the JOINs by hand in Ruby or denormalize (i.e. maintain multiple copies of the data so that your JOINs are precomputed and you only have to access one collection at a time), both of these options tend to be a bit unpleasant and error prone. Are the `embeds_many :images` and `belongs_to :content` right? I don't think you're supposed to be mixing embedding and relations like that.

Comment: My bad! The Image is actually `embedded_in :content`. I'll correct that.

Comment: You're still stuck with multiple queries because there are multiple connections. Or you could keep a copy of the site name in the `web_pages` collection (and keep it synchronized with the name in `sites`) so that you'd still be in just one collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since I still need to iterate over the multiple collections, the best I've come up with is:

```
def build_image_details(site)
  {}.tap do |hash|
    pages = WebPage.where(site: site)
    images = pages.collect { |page| page.content.images }.flatten
    images.each { |image| hash[image.title] = image.bytes }
  end # tap
end
```

That method returns a hash that looks like:

```
{
  "Some Image Title" => 2346435,
  "Another Image Title" => 598438
  # etc.
}
```

I have to query to get the pages, then query each page to gather the images (via the content). But it works.